# Using a trained neural network model in a fortran code

Tags: python, tensorflow, fortran, julia, artificial-intelligence

I am now working on a software coded in fortran
and we are thinking to use machine learning models
in it. I have been training models in python tensorflow
and Julia Flux, but now I need to use the trained models
in the fortran code.

For tensorflow, I have seen that it is possible following the
solution proposed in the link
https://github.com/putschblos/fortran_calls_tensorflow
Yet this solution is quite tedious and I don't manage to use it.

As for Julia I am exploring the possibility of embedding Julia
code in fortran, adapting what can be done in python
(https://github.com/nbren12/call_py_fort).

Is there a more elegant and time efficient way to do this?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Check also https://github.com/modern-fortran/neural-fortran which supports interfacing popular deep-learning frameworks but also has algorithms implemented on its own. I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Your question might be too broad or open-ended for this site. Sites like https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/fortran-and-neural-networks/1268 are more suited for open-ended discussions.

Comment: Hum, so I looked a bit closer to this solution and so it seems it consists in training/applying neural networks entirely in fortran. There are 2 issues with this :

Comment: 1. I must take the time to learn how to dothis

Comment: 2. I do not think there is a big community that could help if I have troubles using this. Thus I would prefer if there were a way to use tensorflow/Flux pre-models.

Comment: As I wrote, neural-fortran does interface to popular deep-learning frameworks such as Keras. If you look at **Features**, the secondone is **Loading dense and convolutional models from Keras HDF5 (.h5) files**. You have to read some documentation first, though. The community around it is quite active, even if not big. See https://www.hindawi.com/journals/sp/2020/8888811/

Comment: My bad, just saw you can import a keras pre-trained model, which is what I'm looking for. The only issue now is if I want to do the same with a Julia Flux pretrained model, since The models are saved in bson, but I don't know if they can be saved in hdf5. Would anyone know if there is a way to use Julia Flux models in neural-fortran?

Comment: Or would anyone know how to save Flux models in hdf5?

Comment: I noticed you posted a reaction in the form of an answer. But it contained many new questions. This site is not good for open-ended discussions and questions with multiple points. Consider asking at  https://fortran-lang.discourse.group instead. The authors of neural-fortran also come there. For stack Overflow, the [tour] and [ask] and [answer] will tell you what is expected here.